# Parameterize ALTER/DROP TABLE OdbcCommand in C#

Tags: c#, sql, odbc, parameterized-query

I am trying to convert the SQL statements in my code from concatenated strings to parameterized queries, but I can not make it work for `DROP TABLE` and `ALTER TABLE` like these:

```
using (OdbcCommand delCmd = new OdbcCommand($"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ?", dbConnection))
{
    delCmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("?", OdbcType.NVarChar) { Value = tableName });
    delCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}


using (OdbcCommand delCmd = new OdbcCommand($"ALTER TABLE ? DROP COLUMN ?", dbConnection))
{
    delCmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("?", OdbcType.NVarChar) { Value = tableName });
    delCmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("?", OdbcType.NVarChar) { Value = columnName });
    delCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I have tried adding `[]` or `''` to either the query string or the parameter, but I never got it to work.

I get **run time error:**

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect 
>   syntax near '@P1'. `

Any suggestions as to how I can get these queries to work would be a big help!

Comment: You can't use parameters for table and column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't provide *table, field names* as *parameters*; but you can use *formatting* or *string interpolation*:

```
 //TODO: validate tableName and columnName here 
 //since formatting / string interpolation prone to SQL injection
 // e.g. 
 // if (!Regex.IsMatch(tableName, "^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*$")) {/* wrong table */}

 using (OdbcCommand delCmd = new OdbcCommand(
   $"ALTER TABLE {tableName} DROP COLUMN {columnName}", 
     dbConnection)) 
 { 
     delCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks :) That was pretty much what I had concluded, just did not find any source telling me I could not do it.